# React & SVG max width

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, reactjs

I want to use max-width in a React component. I tried both `max-width` and `maxWidth` attributes , but it looks like that it's omitted from the element when I inspect it. 
(When I put it in the CSS it works.)

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `style` attribute. See [Inline Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).

```
<div style={{ maxWidth: 250 }}></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You must have copied the code from somewhere else so, please check the if there is ";" semicolon inside inline styling, because react doesn't support that. Use syntax like the following:

```html
<div style={{maxWidth: "100px"}}></div>
```